# Inject a statement from the Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc

I'm writing an MVC 3 app and I have tried to code a control in the Controller (due to permissions, different menu items will be visible for different users) and use the object in the Razor page.  For example, in the `Controller` I do something like:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var menu = "@(Html.Telerik().Menu().Name("menu").Items("menus => { menus.Add().Text("Home").Action("Index", "Home"); menus.Add().Text("Deliveries").Action("Index", "Delivery"); }))";

    var model = new MenuModel()
    {
        Menu = menu
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

And in the `View` I try to render the Menu using `@Model.Menu` but I just get the `string` value rather than an actual menu.  Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: Why are you trying to use Razor in a controller? This code belongs to a view. Don't mix controller logic with presentation logic.

Comment: I can't put the Razor logic in the Razor View because I don't know what it will be at that point.

Comment: Why don't you know what it will be at that point? The Telerik helpers are highly customizable allowing you to generate different markup based on different conditions and values in your model. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend the `HtmlHelper` class and use the newly created method to render your menu in the View:

**Helper:**

```
public static string RenderMenu(this HtmlHelper html)
{
    var menu = new StringBuilder();

    /* ... menu rendering logic ... */

    return menu.ToString();
}
```

**View:**

```
@Html.RenderMenu();
```

Nevertheless, it is fine to put this logic in the view. Using the `HtmlHelper` extension just separates/cleans the code.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do this?  This is breaking the separation of concerns in MVC - your controller shouldn't worry about *how* the menu is displayed, just getting the right data to the view for display.

If you want to do security trimming, don't pass in a builder string.  There are other methods available.

1. You could try the [MVC SiteMap provider](http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/) which can handle security trimming against the [Authorize] controller attributes (bit of work to learn and setup, but great once its there).
2. Pass in your own collection of flags or pre-build menu items, [like what Greg suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9687282/246561).
3. Make a HtmlHelper extension, something like 'IsAuthorized()' that will check against the controller authorize attributes.  [Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/2029462) of one I used to use before switching to the MVC Sitemap.

With the html helper, you can do this:

```
 @(Html.Telerik().Menu()
    .Name("Menu")
    .Items(m =>
    {
        @* Publicly Accessible Controller *@
        m.Add()
            .Text("Home").Url(Url.Action("Index", "Home"));

        @* Secure Controller *@
        if (Html.IsAuthorized<MyProject.Controllers.SecureController>(c => c.Index()))
        {
            //m.Add()....
        }
      .....
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't want to do it that way even if it were possible!

You should decouple your controller and view more than you are currently doing.

The controller should only pass data the view requires. If the view needs a menu with different menu items then use the controller to decide what menu items the view should have then add them to a list object and pass that list to the view. The view will then build a menu based on the list of menu items.

Also when I say "menu items" I don't mean markup! I mean create a new MenuItemViewModel object to persist your data between your controller and your view e.g pseudo code:

```
public class MenuItemViewModel { string url, string text }
List<MenuItemViewModel> menuitems ...
return View(menuitems)
```